# Проблемы с JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Когда жмешь на разные ссылки меняется состав дива. И меняются ссылки, но функция  a_parent плохо работает, что-бы она норм работала, надо кликнуть на a_parent два раза

```
function s(){
    document.getElementById('a_scholar').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('info_area').innerHTML = '<a href=""><p class="a_parent_scholar" id="a_parent">Родителям</p></a><a href=""><p class="a_teacher_scholar" id="a_teacher">Учителям</p></a><a href=""><p class="a_scholar" id="a_scholar">Ученикам</p></a><ul class="body_info_area"><li>Знание домашнего задания на любой день и урок</li><li>Своевременное оповещение о различных мероприятих в твоей школе</li><li>Передача сообщений в любое время суток, учителям, родителям и ученикам</li><li>Вы всегда в курсе последних новостей вашей школы</li><li>Просмотр своей статистики успеваемости</li><li>Своевременное оповещение об экстренных ситуациях</li></ul>';    
        return false;
    }
    document.getElementById('a_parent').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('info_area').innerHTML = '<a href=""><p class="a_scholar_parent" id="a_scholar">Ученикам</p></a><a href=""><p class="a_teacher_parent" id="a_teacher">Учителям</p></a><a href=""><p class="a_parent" id="a_parent">Родителям</p><ul class="body_info_area"><li>Вы всегда знаете оценки своего ребенка</li> <li>Вы знаете домашние задание на любой день и по любому предмету</li> <li>Передача сообщений в любое время суток, учителям, родителям или ученикам</li> <li>Вы всегда в курсе последних новостей вашей школы</li>   <li>Просмотр статистики успеваемости ребенка</li><li>Своевременное получение жалоб от учителей</li><li>Немедленное оповещение об экстренных ситуациях</li></ul>';
        return false;
    }
    document.getElementById('a_teacher').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('info_area').innerHTML = '<a href=""><p class="a_parent_teacher" id="a_parent">Родителям</p></a><a href=""><p class="a_scholar_teacher" id="a_scholar">Ученикам</p></a><a href=""><p class="a_teacher" id="a_teacher">Учителям</p></a><ul class="body_info_area"><li>Передача сообщений в любое время суток, учителям, родителям и ученикам</li > <li>Просмотр и написание новостей класса или школы</li> <li>Написание жалоб, родителям</li> <li>Удобный способ комуникации с родителями</li> <li>Возможность создавать межшкольные мероприятия</li> <li>Просмотр статистики ученика, класса или школы</li><li>Выставление оценок, и Домашнего задание для определенного класса</li><li>Своевременное оповещение об экстренных ситуациях</li></ul>';
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пересоздаёте элементы `( a_scholar, a_parent, a_teacher )`, странно что вообще работает во второй раз....
Лучше не использовать такой код, а сделать структуру на вложенных **div**, и скрывать/показывать их.